# Access variable from iframe without editing iframe page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to access variable from iframe **without** editing iframeContent.html page. I don't know why alert window still shows 'undefined'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var iframe0=0;
    var iframe0document=0;
    var inputIframe=0;      

    function getIframeText() {
        var iframe0 = document.getElementById("iframe123");
        var iframe0document=iframe0.contentDocument||iframe0.contentWindow.document;
        var inputIframe = iframe0document.getElementById("wynik2");
        alert(inputIframe.value);
    };
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div>
    <button onclick="getIframeText()">get iframe text</button>
    <iframe id="iframe123" src="iframeContent.html" >

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

iframeContent.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>IFrame Child Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

var asd="12";

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wynik2"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("wynik2").innerHTML=asd;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Frame on parent page looks good (shows number 12). I'm testing my page on Chrome but through command window typing 'allow file access from files'. So this isn't problem. Global variables are also set (am I doing it right?) so I don't know why is still udefined.

Comment: I would really hope this is not possible because of security implications.

Comment: Thanks for comment, but is there any possibility to grab this value from iframe and put it in variable? (in other project i want to do some math equations with value from iframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use inputIframe.innerText instead of inputIframe.value . "wynik2" is a div, right? cheers! :)

Comment: @iwona: you're welcome. dont forget to accept my answer. Thanks :)